# Does curvature of spacetime changes the wavelength of light?

Tags: general-relativity

Suppose we do an experiment on earth and light a monochromatic light near a highly dense object. Does it cause any change in the wavelength of light?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound–Rebka_experiment